# Inner-join in sql with contains condition

Tags: sql, inner-join, contains, exacttarget

I have 2 tables like this,

**Table1**

```
Id     Locations
--     ---------
1      India, Australia
2      US , UK
```

**Table2**

```
Table2Id    Location
--------    --------
101         Italy
102         UK
103         Hungary
104         India
```

I need to inner join these 2 tables on the condition, If `Locations` in table2 contains  `Location` field in table1. The result will be like

```
Id   Table2Id    Location     Locations
--   --------    --------     ---------
1     104        India        India, Australia
2     102        UK           US , UK
```

I tried something like

```
Select t1.id,
       t2.Table2Id,
       t1.Locations,
       t2.Location
From Table1 t1 
Inner join Table2 t2 On CONTAINS(t1.Locations, t2.Location)
```

But the second parameter of `contains` should be a string. Its not allowing to give the column name there.

I cannot use `temptable` or `variable` in the query. Because this query needs to be run on a email campaign tool called `ExactTarget` where there is no support for `temptable` and `variables`.

Any help will be highly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a3e4) for MySQL 5.5
[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a3e4/1) for SQL

**Table and data**

```
create table table1 (id int, locations varchar(100));
insert into table1 values 
(1, 'India, Australia'),
(2, 'US, UK');

create table table2 (table2id int, location varchar(100));
insert into table2 values
(101, 'Italy'),
(102, 'UK'),
(103, 'Hungary'),
(104, 'India');
```

**MySQL query**

```
select
  table1.id,
  table2.table2id,
  table2.location,
  table1.locations
from table1
join table2 on table1.locations like concat('%', table2.location, '%')
```

**SQL Server query**

```
select
  table1.id,
  table2.table2id,
  table2.location,
  table1.locations
from table1
join table2 on table1.locations like '%' + table2.location + '%'
```

**Edit**

In case where US location is contained in the country name Australia, the above query may not work as desired. To work around that problem, here's a possible query to use

```
select
  table1.id,
  table2.table2id,
  table2.location,
  table1.locations
from table1
join table2 on 
  ',' + replace(table1.locations,', ', ',') + ',' like '%,' + table2.location + ',%'
```

This query forces `India, Australia` to become `,India,Australia,`. This is then compared with `,US,` and therefore will not suffer from incorrect results.

Comment: @Rimas good eye. `',' + replace(table1.locations,', ', ',') + ',' like '%,' + table2.location + ',%'` in the join might look ugly but may do the trick

Comment: @AnoopJoshi You are quite welcome. Hope you can tweak this query to your needs

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mysql you could take a look at the following option: 
[INSTR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr)

```
select table2id, location, table1.id, locations
from table2 inner join table1 on instr(locations,location) >= 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6284a/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to the SQL world and I faced this exact problem. Much bigger than this actually but this was the last piece of the puzzle to get what I wanted.

Here's how I solved it:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 CROSS JOIN t2
WHERE t1.Locations CONTAINS t2.Location;
```

Use the `CONTAINS` according to the language we're using.

To think how close I came to giving up on the puzzle and how simple the solution really was.